# javascript push object property value into existing angular/node application pushes in " ":12 and not 12

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ajax, javascript-objects

So I have an Angular/Node  mean stack app.   but the question is certainly circling around javascript

**my response object comes back with sql identity id**

```
console.log(response.recordset[0]);
```

Above displays   `"":12`

I am wanting to set `12` to my `script.id`

```
script.Id = response.recordset[0];
```

Obviously I do not want that other part,  how do I not include it?

I try to push data which shows in grid column as  `{"":12}`

```
vm.myData.push(script);
```

I have tried below and that is undefined

```
response.recordset[0].value;
```

[image]

Comment: substr, regexp, etc

Comment: seems like that has to be a method that deals with this ,    I see  `0: Object` then in this  `"": 12`

Comment: to me it looks like a string....without knowing the real structure it is hard to guess from your code. `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: {"recordsets":[[{"":14}]],"recordset":[{"":14}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1,1]}

Comment: what returns items without a key? yikes.

Comment: `response.recordset[0][""]`

Comment: angular/node express -->  ms sql ...  it is returning just an `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: I added an image  ,  let me try your code  , hang on   thx

Comment: works ,  if you want to make a quick answer for me ...  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array with an object/ So you will need to reference the first index `0` and reference it by the poorly named key `""`

```
response.recordset[0][""]
```

The recordsets one is an array with an array with an object

```
response.recordsets[0][0][""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your data model. Try to avoid using an empty string as a property key. Also, you're trying to access

```
 response.recordset[0].value;
```

Are you sure there is an explicit "value" property in your object?

Comment: NO,  sad thing is that I even said in my question that this `response.recordset[0].value;` is undefined